# setTimeoutAfter in NotificationCompat.Builder doesn't work

Tags: android, android-notifications

I see this method in docs:

`public NotificationCompat.Builder setTimeoutAfter(long durationMs)`

*Specifies the time at which this notification should be canceled, if it is not already canceled.*

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setTimeoutAfter(long)

Docs say nothing about compatibility, but, when I try to use this method on devices lower than API 26 - it doesn't work. My code:

```
// Init channel with default importance if api >= 26
initNotificationsChannel()

val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Text")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTimeoutAfter(5000)
        .build()

notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
```

Is this behaviour a bug?

Comment: try using setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: It seems setTimeoutAfter is still being ignored on newer Huawei devices. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeoutAfter` was only added in API level 26.

It will be ignored (when used in a `NotificationCompat.Builder`) on older platforms.

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setTimeoutAfter(long))

Comment: Yes, seems like you're right, but it quite strange - add not working method to compat class.

Comment: This is absolutely ludicrous. Can't think of a good reason this is not implemented in lesser api levels.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following workaround:

```
notificationManagerCompat.notify(ID, myNotification);
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed (() -> {
    notificationManagerCompat.cancel(ID);
}, DELAY);
```